# How to get current Windows Login Name in C# Web APP?

Tags: c#

How can I get the user name of Windows Login?
I used these methods:

- Environment.UserName
- WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

But, when I PUT this inside IIS server, it takes the name of the server, not my machine.

Comment: I added a couple of links for you to investigate. HTH!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Page.User.Identity.Name`. This should be what you're looking for. This property is derived from `HttpContext` and represents the logged in user security information for the current HTTP request.

If the result is null, then I would suspect that the IIS settings is not configured properly. Try the advice in the following links:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1689878.aspx/1 
[HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571036/httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-is-empty)

Comment: Then no user is logged in, or you don't have any authorization methods for the specific pages.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm inside the lan, when I use VS localhost working but the app inside IIS not work.

Comment: @soamazing That is because Casini works different that IIS.  Again, either your application or IIS is not configured to automatically log people in using the domain, or some other type of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Use this
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserName")

Comment: If the site is hosted through IIS, you get the IIS username for that application. @code4life's answer is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

https://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/

Here are the main examples from the link above:

Scenario 1: Anonymous Authentication in IIS with impersonation off.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  -> COMPUTER1\IUSR_COMPUTER1
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated -> False
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name  -> –
System.Environment.UserName -> ASPNET
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name    -> COMPUTER1\ASPNET
```

Scenario 2: Windows Authentication in IIS, impersonation off.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  -> MYDOMAIN\USER1
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated -> True
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name  -> MYDOMAIN\USER1
System.Environment.UserName -> ASPNET
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name    -> COMPUTER1\ASPNET
```

Scenario 3: Anonymous Authentication in IIS, impersonation on

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  -> COMPUTER1\IUSR_COMPUTER1
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated -> False
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name  -> –
System.Environment.UserName -> IUSR_COMPUTER1
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name    -> COMPUTER1\IUSR_COMPUTER1
```

Scenario 4: Windows Authentication in IIS, impersonation on

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  -> MYDOMAIN\USER1
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated -> True
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name  -> MYDOMAIN\USER1
System.Environment.UserName -> USER1
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name    -> MYDOMAIN\USER1
```

Note:

```
SERVER1\ASPNET: Identity of the running process on server.
SERVER1\IUSR_SERVER1: Anonymous guest user defined in IIS.
MYDOMAIN\USER1: The user of the remote client.
```