# Get a user name from Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, intranet

I have a small web application which is being currently hosted in a Virtual Machine. The machine has Windows 8 + IIS 7.

As part of the application, I need to get the user name of the people who visit this bloody web application. But every time that I tried to get the current user, I always get the Virtual Machine name.

How can I correctly get the name of the machine, who visit that app. on the Virtual Machine?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC? You should only use the `model-view-controller` tag when you have a question specifically about the design pattern. Tag with `asp.net-mvc` when you have a question about the framework.

Comment: I already used " GetIPHost.HostName" ,  "Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()" and "Environment.UserName". But did not work..

Comment: `user name of the people who visit this bloody web application`. Are the users signed in with Active Directory?

Comment: Yes Drew Kennedy. All users signed in with Active Directory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is logged in via Active Directory, this *should* work:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get "IIS APPPOOL\<myWeb>" as user name..

Comment: It sounds like you may have anonymous logon enabled in IIS. Make sure that's disabled, and also enable integrated security.

Comment: Thanks Drew Kennedy.. Now the problem solved..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608486/how-to-get-current-windows-login-name-in-c-sharp-web-app

Answer (score 0):

On the controller, whether with Windows or Forms Auth, you should be able to get the user via:

```
this.User.Identity.Name
```

Or from the HTTP Context:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```