# Windows authentication in C# without password

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, authentication, ldap

I have a windows forms project that uses [PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx)

Everything works fine, but...

First, a user logs in to windows environment by using his/her windows username and password. Then, this user logs in to my app by using his/her windows username and password. This is a duplicate work isn't ?

My goal is to create something like SSMS's windows authentication (if you connect to DB selecting windows authentication it doesn't ask for your windows password because you are already logged in). So I want to get currently logged-in user's username and something like (Hash, GUID, SID etc.) and use that info to authenticate user.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608486/how-to-get-current-windows-login-name-in-c-sharp-web-app

Comment: @amit how is that relevant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authenticate user in WinForms (Nothing to do with ASP.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873717/authenticate-user-in-winforms-nothing-to-do-with-asp-net)

Comment: @MickyD User has not mentioned whether it is webapp or windows forms app. He just mentions environment is windows. If it is windows app, i think that will be far easier to log in with user credentials automatically.

Comment: I guess you would need to provide more details about - why do you use `ValidateCredentials` ? In a WinForms application, [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=netframework-4.7#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity_GetCurrent) gives the current Windows user. There is no need to do "authentication" again. It is already the authenticated user.

Comment: @Amit.  Incorrect - _"I have a windows forms project"_

Comment: @Amit User already mentioned its a windows forms project

Comment: I have the same question, @Subbu You are right. but what if I want to send mail to someone in my application using the local mail server, then it needs password... How can I get the password, without letting user to give it. to the app?.. Or You might suggest I send Mail without password Authentication..??