# User.Identity.Name is blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have done a bunch of research about this, but can't find a solution to this problem.

my web.config :

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

and for some reason

```
string User = User.Identity.Name;
```

is always blank.

IIS Windows authentication is the only option that is enabled.

i have tried the

```
[Authorize]
```

same result.

I checked the IIS config file to make sure

```
  <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
```

is set to true.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5458963/4843530

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working within an authorized context? In other words, unless you actually say you want a particular controller or action authorized, nothing is filled even if the user has previously logged in. For example:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var user = User.Identity.Name; // null
}
```

But

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
   var user = User.Identity.Name; // WIN
}
```

If you need the action to still allow anonymous access, just add `[AllowAnonymous]` as well:

```
[Authorize]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ...
```