# I need to get the current user name in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, but it always comes back as null.  I have Anonymous Authentication set to disabled and Windows Authentication set to Enabled in the project properties.  I also have the below lines in my web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>

<providers>
....
  <add name="WindowsProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
</providers>
```

[image: Server settings]

Every post I have looked at has suggested doing the steps I have already done, but I still have no luck.

Comment: Hosted in IIS  or checking in VS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571036/httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-is-empty)

Comment: Just checking in VS on localhost

Comment: Also make sure you aren't trying to access the HttpContext identity too early in the application pipeline, such as in the Application_Start method of the Global.asax, as the identity won't be available there.

Comment: Thanks Thomas!  You were correct, I was getting the null error as soon as I ran the application.  I moved the code into where I needed to get the user and it's working correctly now.  If you make an answer I will mark it.

Comment: I don't understand why people mark my question as a duplicate and downvote it within 10 minutes of posting.  The duplicate question's answer is explicitly stated to not work in my post.

Comment: I think a useful addition to the question would have been to include the context of your calling code that was throwing the exception, so that the problem would have been immediately obvious. I just guessed problem from the symptom in this case. To learn more about duplicate guidelines and why its useful for members to link to potential duplicates, I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out with this

```
string userName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

or

```
User.Identity.Name
```